# Cannot extract wso2 IdP SAML metadata

Tags: metadata, wso2, extract, saml

I'm trying to use wso2 as SAML2 IdP and I need to extract the IdP metadata.

Do you know how I can do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posting the answer since somebody else will be looking for it.
WSO2 IS at the moment does not have the capability to auto generate the metadata file.
But you can use the metadata file [here](https://svn.wso2.org/repos/wso2/people/tanya/IS_metadata.xml) which is prepared following the standards.

Comment: i used your link to generate SAML metadata but still facing some issues, can you help?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the url: `https://localhost:9443/samlsso`

This blog post seems to describe what you are trying to achieve: [link](http://blog.facilelogin.com/2013/06/wso2-identity-server-saml2-idp-with.html)